# Onchage pass 2 values

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables

Hello is there a way in a dropdown select element to pass in OnChange function 2 values, one of which should be the value selected and the other a PHP variable ?

something like this :

```
<div>
    <?php   
        $sql4 = "SELECT DISTINCT (color), id FROM mytable ORDER BY id ASC ";    
        $result4 = $conn->query($sql4);
    ?>
    <select onchange="function(this.value,$row4['name'])" class="form-control selectpicker" data-size="10" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-white" name="my_name" required  >
        <?php 
            if ($result4->num_rows > 0) 
            {
                while($row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()) 
                {
                if($row4['id']>0)
                {
        ?>
        <option value="<?=$row4['id'];?>"><?=$row4['name'];?></option>
        <?php }}}?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your desired function is

```
myFunction(value, name){}
```

Use  tag inside the string

```
<div>
    <?php   
        $sql4 = "SELECT DISTINCT (color), id FROM mytable ORDER BY id ASC ";    
        $result4 = $conn->query($sql4);
    ?>
    <select onchange="myFunction(this.value,'<?php echo $row4['name'] ?>')" class="form-control selectpicker" data-size="10" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-white" name="my_name" required  >
        <?php 
            if ($result4->num_rows > 0) 
            {
                while($row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()) 
                {
                if($row4['id']>0)
                {
        ?>
        <option value="<?=$row4['id'];?>"><?=$row4['name'];?></option>
        <?php }}}?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried it but didn't workout. What if i want to pass only the php variable and not the value ?

Comment: You mean variable name?

Answer (score 0):

1. `function` is a protected keyword, you can't call a function "function"
2. to access the selected option in a `select` dropdown we use `selectedIndex` or `selectedOptions` but not `value`.

```html
<div>
    <?php   
        $sql4 = "SELECT DISTINCT (color), id FROM mytable ORDER BY id ASC ";    
        $result4 = $conn->query($sql4);
    ?>
    <select onchange="myFunction(event, <?php echo $row4['name'] ?>)" class="form-control selectpicker" data-size="10" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-white" name="my_name" required  >
        <?php 
            if ($result4->num_rows > 0) 
            {
                while($row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()) 
                {
                if($row4['id']>0)
                {
        ?>
        <option value="<?=$row4['id'];?>"><?=$row4['name'];?></option>
        <?php }}}?>
    </select>
</div>
```

```js
function myFunction(event, rowName) {
    const select = event.target;
    const selectedOptions = select.selectedOptions;
    // …
}
```

Comment: What if i want to pass only the php variable and not the value ?

Comment: If you don't need the selected option(s) you can remove the `event` parameter in HTML code as well as in the function declaration

Comment: to be more clear i have this <select onchange="myFuction(this.value)">  <option value="<?=$row4['id'];?>"><?=$row4['name'];?></option>. Now  instead of the this.value i want to pass the $row4['name'] to the function

Comment: But don't you want the parameter to different depending on which option the user has choosen?